# Cannot ignore module with ES6

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to tell Jest to "not" ignore one of the modules "bpmn-moddle" in the node_modules folder, but it is not happening. This is my config:

```js
module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '\\.(gql|graphql)$': 'jest-transform-graphql'
  },
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  testResultsProcessor: './node_modules/luis/dist/bridges/jest/reporter',
  watchPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/src/summary.json', '<rootDir>/src/snapshots.js'],
  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: '<rootDir>/jest.setup.js',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.*[.](css|CSS)$': '<rootDir>/test/styleMock.js',
    '^.*[.](jpg|gif|png|ttf|eot|svg)$': '<rootDir>/test/fileMock.js'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(bpmn-moddle)/)']
};
```

It seems that transform Ignore patterns is not kicking in. When I change it to:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['/!node_modules\\/bpmn-moddle']
```

It seems to work, but in my opinion is compiling whole node_modules as it takes a LONG time to complete.

Comment: Hey did you ever get a solution to this?